# How can we use fgetpos() to get the size of a file

Tags: c, gcc

How can we use `fgetpos()` to get the size of a file? I actually want to display the file size of a large file(3-10 Gb)

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to use `fstat`?

Comment: Actually see "fgetpos" in [any random online C reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetpos/).

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
FILE * fp = fopen(filename, "r");

// seek to the end
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

fpos_t flesize;
// get current position
fgetpos(fp, &flesize);
```

I would rather recommend `fstat` though:

```
struct stat file_stat;
fstat(fileno(fp), &file_stat);

printf("File size : %zd bytes\n", file_stat.st_size);
```

Comment: I agree with you. `fstat` is a better function. The standard strictly says the returned value of `fgetpos` is to be used strictly in `fsetpos`.

Comment: `fseek()` and  `SEEK_END` is not a portable way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

With fgetpos(), the file pointer would have to traverse through the whole file ( 3 - 10 GB)!! While with a simple system call stat / fstat, you get the size via the structure member st_size.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fstat()`

```
File *fd = fopen("filename");
struct stat s;
fstat(fileno(fd), &s);
printf("file size: %lu\n", s.st_size);
```

Comment: `%d` prints `int` which will most likely default to a 32-bit integer and thus be unable to capture the whole  beauty of `off_t` which `s.st_size` happens to be.